# Volume between two cylinders?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate volume of region between the cylinders x^2+y^2=36 and x^2+z^2=36. How can I code it in mathematica? and there is also another question form like this one. [image]

I wanna calculate this also.
Thanks.

Comment: I dont think so because when I put my functions there, I get several errors :(

Comment: Please include in your question the code you are using.

Comment: `Volume@{ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 <= 49, z >= 0, x + z <= 4}, {x, y, 
    z}], ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 <= 49, z <= 0, x + z >= 4}, {x, y, 
    z}]}`

Comment: `ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 <= 36, x^2 + z^2 <= 36}, {x, y, 
   z}] // Volume`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 <= 49, z >= 0, x + z <= 4}, {x, y, z}]
Volume[reg]
(*2 (19 Sqrt[33] + 49 \[Pi] + 98 ArcSin[4/7])*)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This output scared to me. Is there anyway to convert this  like 144π or 500π?

Comment: Obviously the result isn't a product of `Pi` with some number!